# how to use readonly in an ng-select?

Tags: angular

my question is in relation to the `readonly` of the angular in a select.

```
 <select-pesquisa-produto 
         [readonly]="disableEdit" 
         focusNext" 
         formControlName="produtoId">
 </select-pesquisa-produto>
```

in my `ngOnInit` in the component I have an if that changes the condition of the disableEdit to true

```
if (this.data) { this.desabilitarEdicaoProduto = true;}
```

but the angular is still leaving the select active for change, and if I use the disable it is considering the value of the field as null

any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the field. You just need to enable it again on submit so that the value of the field isn't set to null (replace `myForm` with your form's name):
`this.myForm.controls['produtoId'].enable();`